# vuejs using Quasar framework how to submit the form using a button from outside the form control

Tags: vue.js, quasar

*here is my code*

```
<!-- ParentComponent.vue -->
<script setup>
import ChildForm from '../components/ChildForm.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const testData = ref({
  name: 'abcd',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
});

function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const newname = formData.get('name');
  const newEmail = formData.get('email');

  console.log('Printing the name property:', newname);
  console.log('Printing the email property:', newEmail);
}
</script>

<template>
  <q-form @submit="onSubmit">
    <ChildForm :testData="testData" />
  </q-form>

  <q-btn
    class="q-ml-md"
    color="primary"
    label="Save"
    no-caps
    type="submit"
    @click="onSubmit()"
  />
</template>

<!-- Child component -->
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['testData']);
</script>

<template>
  <!-- eslint-disable vue/no-mutating-props -->
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-y-md column">
      <q-list>
        <q-input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          label="Name"
          v-model="props.testData.name"
        />
        <q-input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          label="Email"
          v-model="props.testData.email"
        />
      </q-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

*while executing with above code it has gives the error msg as *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')**

*after searched on web for how to submit the form from outside the form control i got some idea suggested by googlebard tried this below one.
this time give error msg as *Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function**

```
<script setup>
import ChildForm from '../components/ChildForm.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const testData = ref({
  name: 'abcd',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
});

const formRef = ref(null);

function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get the form element.
  const form = formRef.value;

  // Get the form data.
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  // Get the name and email properties from the form data.
  const newname = formData.get('name');
  const newEmail = formData.get('email');

  console.log('Printing the name property:', newname);
  console.log('Printing the email property:', newEmail);
}
</script>

<template>
  <q-form ref="formRef" @submit="onSubmit">
    <ChildForm :testData="testData" />
  </q-form>

  <q-btn
    class="q-ml-md"
    color="primary"
    label="Save"
    no-caps
    type="submit"
    @click="onSubmit(formRef)"
  />
</template>
```

again i asked the bard.ggogle.com to resolve the issue, this time i get suggetion by bard and tried that also failed

```
<script setup>
import ChildForm from '../components/ChildForm.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const testData = ref({
  name: 'abcd',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
});

const formRef = ref(null);

function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get the form element.
  const form = formRef.value;

  // Get the form data.
  const formData = new FormData(form);

  // Get the name and email properties from the form data.
  const newname = formData.get('name');
  const newEmail = formData.get('email');

  console.log('Printing the name property:', newname);
  console.log('Printing the email property:', newEmail);
}
</script>

<template>
  <q-form ref="formRef" @submit="onSubmit">
    <ChildForm :testData="testData" />
  </q-form>

  <q-btn
    class="q-ml-md"
    color="primary"
    label="Save"
    no-caps
    type="submit"
    @click="onSubmit(event)"
  />
</template>
```

now error msg shown as *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')*
this many ways i was tried, how i can achieve this